# Embeded interface : struct doesn't implement method

Tags: go

I don't understand why interface composition doesn't " inherit"  the methods from the parent interface when it is satisfied in the implementation.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TestRepository interface {
    FindById(int) (error)
}

type TestService interface {
    TestRepository
    Method(id int) error
}



type testService struct {
    implRepository TestRepository
}

func NewTestService(r TestRepository) TestService {
    return &testService{implRepository: r}
}
```

When compiling this code i'm getting : `*testService does not implement TestService (missing FindById method)` while i'm actually expecting it to implement it since the type of "implRepository" is TestRepository.

It works if i do :

```
func NewTestService(r TestRepository) *testService {
    return &testService{implRepository: r}
}
```

But it kind of defeat the purpose of the interface ( as far as the service one goes at least )

What am i missing / how should it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simply "you aren't composing the interface the way you need to." You have made `TestRepository` a struct member - that is not going to "inherit" the methods on that interface. What you need is the following:

```
type testService struct {
    TestRepository
}

func NewTestService(r TestRepository) TestService {
    return &testService{TestRepository: r}
}
```

Of course, the struct `testService` still need to implement `Method(id int) error` to actually work.